# Inject same stateful ejb instance into different managedbeans

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, managed-bean

I am trying to build a simple blog on JSF. However, I do not know how to inject same stateful ejb instance into 2 different managed beans. I know that injecting could be done  indirectly, by using @ManagedProperty annotation. Something like that:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class PostController implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Post temporaryPost;

@ManagedProperty(value = "#{authenticationController}")
private AuthenticationController authenticationController;

@Inject
private PostEJB postEJB;

public void save() {
    getTemporaryPost().setAuthor(
            getAuthenticationController().getAuthenticationEJB()
                    .getCurrentSessionUser());
    postEJB.create(getTemporaryPost());
}
    }
```

I want to get rid of

> @ManagedProperty(value = "#{authenticationController}")
>   private AuthenticationController authenticationController;

and inject AuthenticationEJB directly, like

> @Inject private AuthenticationEJB authenticationEJB;

So, instead of

> getAuthenticationController().getAuthenticationEJB()
>                           .getCurrentSessionUser()

I will get

> authenticationEJB.getCurrentSessionUser()

But, the problem is that this is new authenticationEJB instance, which do not contain currently logged in user(User is null). At the same time authenticationController.authenticationEJB.currentsessionuser contains logged in user.

Thanks in advance!

---

Finnaly got the answer! It is easy:

```
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{authenticationController.authenticationEJB}")
private AuthenticationEJB authenticationEJB;
```

Now it points to the same authenticationEJB instance. However, I believe there might be some other ways to do it.

Comment: Have yout tried using `@SessionScoped` for `PostController` managed bean?

Comment: Just tried, @SessonScoped did not help.

Comment: For EJBs, I use `@EJB` instead of `@Inject`, maybe that helps you

Comment: Nope, this did not help either. But I have found anwser. I will post it right now!

Comment: Finnaly got the answer! It is easy:

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{authenticationController.authenticationEJB}")
 private AuthenticationEJB authenticationEJB;

Now it points to the same authenticationEJB instance. However, I believe there might be other ways to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you got the answer but maybe couple of notes

- why won't you inject your bean directly to `PostController` with `@EJB` annotation?
- If you develop a new project, use `CDI beans` instead of JSF Managed Beans, they will soon get deprecated (and whole Java EE stack is slowly moving towards using CDI everywhere)
- then you can get rid of `@ManagedProperty`, every bean (which will basically be any class in your application) will get injectable with `@Inject` annotation. Same thing applies for EJBs, so CDI kind of unifies the access to most types of beans.
- some basic CDI + JSF tutorial [here](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/cdi-intro.html)

Comment: Well, thanks for the advices, I am really new to this stack of technologies. I have tried injecting EJB, but as I understood it creates a new EJB instance for postController. Example: postController.authenticationEJB contains different data from authentificationController.authenticationEJB. Thanks for CDI, did not knew that everything changed so dramatically!

Comment: That's true for `stateless` beans but you wrote that your bean is `stateful` so you should get same instance in every bean which is injected to.

Comment: I am really confused, maybe I will check it tomorrow in details. Yes, AuthenticationEJB is Stateful LocalBean.
But when I change ManagedProperty(value = #{authenticationController.authenticationEJB}") to EJB then post cannot be saved because of null in user field (user here is post author). In other case evrything works fine..

Comment: If i use EJB annotation with this JSF: 
<li><a href="#"><h:outputText value="#{authenticationController.authenticationEJB.currentSessionUser.username}" /></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><h:outputText value="#{postController.authenticationEJB.currentSessionUser.username}" /></a></li> 
after login there is output like:
ilja anonymous

So, they do not map to each other. probably?